# Get view/viewgroup on the windows/Screen

Tags: android

Is there any way to get the view/viewgroup on the Screen at particular location,like blackberry provide getFieldAtLocation(x, y) to get the Field at x,y position.

Comment: What do you want? Is your X,Y are per-defined or you want to get it using touch event?

Comment: Actually i want to know which view is rendered on the x,y position.And my x,y pre-defined.

Comment: If you are using TouchListener in your activity, then its provided View as argument in onTouch() method. Then you can verified which view is current touched.